# How to make my cordapp accessible through web?

Tags: corda

I want to make my CordApp to be accessible through web . What is the best way to do it . Currently I am using my Cordapp through terminal .

What is the best way for my goal?

Will using corda-webserver will help me? How to use corda-webserver.jar? Do we create it or we get a template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this [example](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/spring-webserver) which creates a SpringBoot webserver. You can call your flows or query the vault through the RPC connection that you define.

- The example comes in Java and Kotlin.
- Define the [RPC connection](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/spring-webserver/server-java/src/main/java/net/corda/server/NodeRPCConnection.java) that your server will use.
- Define the [SpringBoot app](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/spring-webserver/server-java/src/main/java/net/corda/server/Server.java) (i.e. your webserver).
- Define a [controller](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/spring-webserver/server-java/src/main/java/net/corda/server/controllers/StandardController.java) that will expose your API's.
- Define a [gradle task](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/spring-webserver/server-java/build.gradle) to start your webserver.

Below are examples for Gradle tasks to start the webservers (read the comments in the code):

```
task runPartyAServer(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: assemble) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'com.example.webserver.Server'
    // The server port for PartyA is 10070, while for PartyB it's 10080, 
    // and so on... (you can basically choose any port number, usually it's 8080)
    // Also, I only wrote one parameter `config.rpc.host`, but you need to
    // supply all the parameters that your RPCConnection class is expecting (i.e
    // config.rpc.username, config.rpc.password, config.rpc.port).
    args '--server.port=10070', '--config.rpc.host=localhost', etc....
}

task runPartyBServer(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: assemble) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'com.example.webserver.Server'
    args '--server.port=10080', '--config.rpc.host=localhost', etc....
}
```

Comment: i get the purpose of each individual that you have advised me . But i am not able to connect them. 
As I have multiple nodes in the cordapp, I am not able to understand how the web server is going to connect to the multiple RPC ports . As you know we have to specify our custom webserver by defining in the gradle task of the cordapp I am not able to grasp whether the ClienRPC and Controller will be in my Cordapp or in my SpringBoot server jar ?

Comment: I updated my answer with examples to start servers for multiple nodes. Obviously if your nodes have different API's then you need to create two separate "clients' modules where each controller has a different set of API's.